# Starting arm emulator gives "unknown option: - please use -help for a list of valid options"

Tags: android

Starting arm emulator gives "unknown option: - please use -help for a list of valid options", but there does not seem to be anywhere to see or change the options being used. Does any-one know hows to get around this problem?  Thanks.

Comment: specify how you're launching it. (from within eclipse, what os, etc.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How are you starting the emulator (In AVD Manager? From Eclipse?...)?  Behind the scenes it's just running the command

`<path-to-sdk>\tools\emulator.exe -avd emulatorname`

The error you mentioned is thrown if there are invalid options.  For example, the following:

`<path-to-sdk>\tools\emulator.exe -avd emulatorname -wuioej`

will throw the following error:

> ```
> unknown option: -wuioej  
> please use -help for a list of valid options
> ```

In your case it looks like there's just an extra '-' at the end for some reason, which is why I asked how you're starting the emulator.

Answer (score 2):

I got the same error.

I reinstalled my SDK Manager again, same failure occurs. But there is no logging in AVD Manager so I can't trace the error.

If I start the AVD in the command line it works but the scale is not so pretty.

Also: CMD LINE START:

```
\tools\emulator.exe -avd HTC-TouchHD
```

Works fine.

And start of SDK Manager shows [image: start of SDK Manager]
<sub>(source: [jkoeber.de](http://www.jkoeber.de/uploads/sdkManagerError.jpg))</sub>

Is there any log-file in the system where I can find the executed command in SDK Manager (Win 7 Pro)?

**!!! FOUND THE SOLUTION !!!**

If a path is used with empty spaces the emulator couldn't start the AVD. I found the solution by copying my SDK-manager folder directly to main HDD. So my path is actually set to:

```
d:\sdk-manager
```

before:

```
"d:\android - tools\sdk-manager\"
```